# vuejs области видимости

Tags: vue.js

Сразу к коду

```
Vue.component("component", {
  template: template,
  data() {
    return {
      azaza: ["dasdsa"]
    }
  },
  created() {
    let url = '/url';
    console.log(this.azaza); // тут видит данные
    axios.get(url)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(this.azaza); // а тут уже не видит
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
});
```

не могу понять почему так происходит, что за проколы видимости в колбеке

Comment: проблему устранил заменой function (response) на response =>, но не понял почему так сработало, кто понял объясните плиз

Comment: Стрелочная функция не имеет своей области видимости, поэтому данные в нее свободно попадаются из this.

Comment: Область видимости тут не причем, стрелочная функция не имеет своего контекста, поэтому this не изменяется.